# Compare elements from 2 singly-linked lists and program (usually) crash

Tags: c, file, crash, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I have the project to do. Assumptions are like that:

1. From file with words i need to read only alphabetic words (into list called Words - code below) - I did it by use isalpha() function from  lib. Each element of list contain one word
2. From input file (another file) I need to all read lines (line by line) and save them into another list called Data. (code below) Ofc I needed to split the sentence into words, that's why I used list in list.
3. Now I need check if words from first file are in the second file. If they exist, I must say in which lines. The result I need to save in output file.

I need to process big amount of data, files are few MB of words (like 250k words).

My problem is such that my program worked on small amount of data, like few words. Idk where the problem is. Maybe with allocation of memory? I'm new in C and have to do this project ._ . I have like 500 lines of functions code. I can share it on something like pastebin, or .zip file, or I can talk on Messenger if you have some time.

Here are fragments (structs):

---

```
struct Words
{
  char* word;
  struct Words* pNext;
};

struct Data
{
  int lineNumber;
  struct Words* words;
  struct Data* pNext;
};

typedef struct Data Data;
typedef struct Words Words;
```

---

Main:

---

```
  PrintStartMessage();

  const char* ListOfWords = FindArgument(argc, argv, "-l");
  const char* Input = FindArgument(argc, argv, "-i");
  const char* Output = FindArgument(argc, argv, "-o");

  if(!(IsNameWOExtension(ListOfWords) || IsTxtFile(ListOfWords)) || (!(IsNameWOExtension(Input) || IsTxtFile(Input))))
  {
    ErrorNameFileMessage();
    return 0;
  } /* check if parameters are correct (no extension or filename.txt) */

  Data* data = NULL;
  Words* words = NULL;

  FILE* InputWords = NULL;
  FILE* InputFile = NULL;
  FILE* OutputFile = NULL;
  if(ReadWordsToStruct(&InputWords, ListOfWords, "r", &words) == 0)
  {
    DeleteWords(&words);
    DeleteData(&data);
    return 0;
  }

  if(ReadDataToStruct(&InputFile, Input, "r", &data) == 0)
  {
    DeleteWords(&words);
    DeleteData(&data);
    return 0;
  }

  if(SaveInformationToFile(&OutputFile, Output, "w", words, data) == 0)
  {
    DeleteWords(&words);
    DeleteData(&data);
    return 0;
  }

  PrintSuccessMessage();
  DeleteWords(&words);
  DeleteData(&data);
```

---

Few functions:

---

```
const char* FindArgument(int argc, char* const argv[], char* arg)
{
  int i = 1;
  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
  {
    if(strcmp(arg, argv[i]) == 0)
      return argv[i+1];
  }
}

int IsTxtFile(const char* name)
{
  const char* txt = "txt";
  char fileExtension[4] = "";
  int save = 0; /* index of '.' in name */

  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i<strlen(name); i++)
  {
    if(name[i] == '.')
    {
      save = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(strlen(name) - (save + 1) > 3) /* if after '.' there are more than 3 characters */
    return 0; /* file isn't txt type */

  int counter = 0;
  for(i = save+1; i < save+4; i++)
  {
    if(name[i] != '\0')
    {
      fileExtension[counter] = name[i];
      counter++;
    }
    else
      return 0; /* file isn't txt type */
  }
  if(strcmp(txt,fileExtension) == 0)
    return 1; /* file is txt type */

  return 0; /* file isn't txt type */
}

int OpenFile(FILE** file, const char* filename, char* mode)
{
  if(IsTxtFile(filename) == 1)
    *file = fopen(filename, mode);
  else
  {
    char* something = ConcatenateStrings(filename, ".txt");
    *file = fopen(something, mode);
    free(something);
  }

  if(*file != NULL)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

void CloseFile(FILE** file)
{
  fclose(*file);
}


char* ConcatenateStrings(const char* string1, char* string2)
{
  char *result = (char *)malloc(strlen(string1) + strlen(string2) + 1);
  strcpy(result, string1);
  strcat(result, string2);

  return result;
}

int IsAlphabetical(char* string)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
  {
    if(!isalpha(string[i]))
      return 0; /* isalpha() checks if the passed character is alphabetic */
  }
  return 1;
}

// singly-linked list operations - Words
void AddWords(Words** head, char* word)
{
  Words* temp = *head;
  Words* newWord = (Words *)malloc(sizeof(Words));
  newWord->word = (char *)malloc((strlen(word)+1)*sizeof(char));

  strcpy(newWord->word, word);
  newWord->pNext = NULL;

  if (*head == NULL)
     *head = newWord;
  else
  {
    while(temp->pNext != NULL)
      temp = temp->pNext;

    temp->pNext = newWord;
  }
}

void ReadWordsFromFile(Words** words, FILE* file)
{
  char line[1024];
  char delimiters[] = " \n\0";
  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
  {
    char* token = strtok(line, delimiters);
    while(token != NULL)
    {
      if((IsAlphabetical(token) == 1) && (SearchInWords(*words, token)) == 0)
      {
        char* string = (char *)malloc((strlen(token)+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(string, token);
        AddWords(words, string);
        free(string);
      }
      token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }
  }
}

int ReadWordsToStruct(FILE** file, const char* filename, char* mode, Words** head)
{
  if(OpenFile(file, filename, mode) == 1)
  {
    ReadWordsFromFile(head, *file);
    CloseFile(file);
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    ErrorOpeningFile(filename);
    return 0;
  }
}


// singly-linked list operation - Data
void AddData(Data** head, char* sentence, int number)
{
  Words* words = NULL;
  char delimiters[] = " \n\0";
  char* token = strtok(sentence, delimiters);
  while(token != NULL)
  {
    if(IsAlphabetical(token) == 1)
    {
      char* string = (char *)malloc((strlen(token)+1)*sizeof(char));
      strcpy(string, token);
      AddWords(&words, string);
      free(string);
    }
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
  }


  Data* temp = *head;
  Data* newData = (Data *)malloc(sizeof(Data));

  newData->lineNumber = number;
  newData->words = words;
  newData->pNext = NULL;

  if (*head == NULL)
     *head = newData;
  else
  {
    while(temp->pNext != NULL)
      temp = temp->pNext;

    temp->pNext = newData;
  }
}

void ReadDataFromFile(Data** data, FILE* file)
{
  char line[4096]; /* max-length string */
  int lineCounter = 1;
  while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
  {
    if(IsEmptyString(line) != 1)
    {
      AddData(data, line, lineCounter);
      lineCounter++;
    }
  }
}

int ReadDataToStruct(FILE** file, const char* filename, char* mode, Data** head)
{
  if(OpenFile(file, filename, mode) == 1)
  {
    ReadDataFromFile(head, *file);
    CloseFile(file);
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    ErrorOpeningFile(filename);
    return 0;
  }
}

// processing data

int NumberOfWords(Words* head)
{
  int count = 0;
  Words* temp = head;
  while (temp != NULL)
  {
    count++;
    temp = temp->pNext;
  }
  DeleteWords(&temp);
  return count;
}

char* GetWord(Words* head, int wordNumber)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < wordNumber; i++)
    head = head->pNext;
  return head->word;
}

void FindWordInData(FILE** file, Data* head, char* word)
{
  fprintf(*file, "Word \'%s\' occurs in lines: \n", word);

  Data* temp = head;
  Words* tempWord = temp->words;
  int numberOfOccurrences = 0;
  int j = 0;

  while(temp->pNext != NULL)
 {
   j = 0;
   while(tempWord->pNext != NULL)
   {
     char* wordFromData = GetWord(temp->words, j);
     if(strcmp(word, wordFromData) == 0)
     {
       fprintf(*file, "%d ", temp->lineNumber);
       numberOfOccurrences++;
       break;
     }
     j++;
     tempWord = tempWord->pNext;
     free(wordFromData);
   }
   DeleteWords(&tempWord);
   temp = temp->pNext;
 }
 if(numberOfOccurrences == 0)
  fprintf(*file,"-\n");
 else
  fprintf(*file,"\n");
 DeleteData(&temp);
}

int SaveInformationToFile(FILE** file, const char* filename, char* mode, Words* words, Data* data)
{
  if(OpenFile(file, filename, mode) == 1)
  {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < NumberOfWords(words); i++)
    {
      char* tempWord = GetWord(words, i);
      FindWordInData(file, data, tempWord);
      free(tempWord);
    }
    CloseFile(file);
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    ErrorCreatingFile();
    return 0;
  }
}

// deleting list


void DeleteData(Data** head)
{
  Data* temp = *head;
  while (temp != NULL)
  {
      Data* next = temp->pNext;
      DeleteWords(&temp->words);
      free(temp);
      temp = next;
  }
  free(temp); /* to check that */
  *head = NULL;
}

void DeleteWords(Words** head)
{
  Words* temp = *head;
  while (temp != NULL)
  {
      Words* next = temp->pNext;
      free(temp->word);
      free(temp);
      temp = next;
  }
  free(temp); /* to check that */
  *head = NULL;
```

}

---

Comment: please add the missing lines to make the code in the question a simple working code example

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

function GetWord returns pointer instead of string.
Solution:

```
char* GetWord(Words* head, int wordNumber)
{
  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < wordNumber; i++)
    head = head->pNext;
  char* result = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(head->word) + 1));
  strcpy(result, head->word);
  return result;
}
```